# Ruffle Emulator Error message: Failed to fetch:

Tags: html, flash, ruffle

When I am making my website with ruffle on it, when ever I launch the website the emulator fails to load and I get the error. I am trying to run the flash game Toss The Turle but it will not load

https://github.com/project-lulo/RuffleTest

Here is the error

## Error Info

Error name: Error
Error message: Failed to fetch: https://project-lulo.github.io/508440_tossTheTurtleV1NG.swf
Error stack:

```
Error: Failed to fetch: https://project-lulo.github.io/508440_tossTheTurtleV1NG.swf
    at N.displayRootMovieDownloadFailedMessage (https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle:1:42817)
    at W.n.wbg.__wbg_displayRootMovieDownloadFailedMessage_1a5c34096259685a (https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle/core.ruffle.166543534d0d6de8f27f.js:1:6048)
    at <ruffle_web::ui::WebUiBackend as ruffle_core::backend::ui::UiBackend>::display_root_movie_download_failed_message::h388897a81a8d9e4a (wasm://wasm/01800c06:wasm-function[6009]:0x4a4416)
    at <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::hae136a348136f102 (wasm://wasm/01800c06:wasm-function[529]:0x1b1fd7)
    at <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h226af752124a8ae1 (wasm://wasm/01800c06:wasm-function[1044]:0x2a5ec8)
    at wasm_bindgen_futures::queue::Queue::new::{{closure}}::hde74cc58c6c5c016 (wasm://wasm/01800c06:wasm-function[2316]:0x3c9a4f)
    at <dyn core::ops::function::FnMut<(A,)>+Output = R as wasm_bindgen::closure::WasmClosure>::describe::invoke::haf48995076cdf3b9 (wasm://wasm/01800c06:wasm-function[5490]:0x494e2d)
    at closure2936 externref shim (wasm://wasm/01800c06:wasm-function[5611]:0x49753d)
    at S (https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle/core.ruffle.166543534d0d6de8f27f.js:1:2706)
    at c (https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle/core.ruffle.166543534d0d6de8f27f.js:1:2231)


# Player Info
Allows script access: true
Renderer: WebGL

# Page Info
Page URL: https://project-lulo.github.io/RuffleTest/
SWF URL: https://project-lulo.github.io/508440_tossTheTurtleV1NG.swf

# Browser Info
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14695.85.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Platform: Linux x86_64
Has touch support: false

# Ruffle Info
Version: 0.1.0
Name: nightly 2022-10-14
Channel: nightly
Built: 2022-10-14T00:22:21.438Z
Commit: b0b0e55c240e7d505d1ee64f61764de554885e5f
Is extension: false

# Metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Thanks to [@Project Lulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20151407/project-lulo) for the solution.

Demo: https://vcone.github.io/public/demos/Ruffle1/index.html

You can access files by embedding just the file name (**without** the HTTP part).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle"></script>

<body>

<embed src="508440_tossTheTurtleV1NG.swf" width="500" height="500"></embed>

<body>

</html>
```

**Older Answer:** 
*This applies to loading  files with `<media>` elements but does not work with `<embed>` element...*

Your files are stored at **github.com**, not at the **github.io** location.

Your file path should start as: `https://github.com/project-lulo/RuffleTest/raw/main/`

So the correct URL to **fetch** the SWF is:

```
https://github.com/project-lulo/RuffleTest/raw/main/508440_tossTheTurtleV1NG.swf
```

Comment: That didnt work

Comment: Figued it out! I use the link to site it is https://project-lulo.github.io/RuffleTest/508440_tossTheTurtleV1NG.swf

Comment: @ProjectLuLo Nice one for solving it. It seems you can even just set the SWF filename without HTTP path and that also works. I'll update the answer for future readers.