# Is there a way to host swf in 2022

Tags: flash

Is there a way to host and play an swf file, in a html or php page in 2022? Im trying it with a file writen in action script 2.0
Does it need any conversions?

```
<embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400"></embed>
```

Comment: See if [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74086419/2057709) helps you.

Comment: Why not use any modern format for this? Flash has been deprecated years ago